# Why are module preserving elements units?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a real quadratic field and $M \subset K$ be a subgroup of the additive group of $K$ of rank $2$. Why is each $\varepsilon \in K$ with $\varepsilon M=M$ a unit, so an element of $\mathcal O_K^\times$?

**What I tried:** We can find a basis $b_1,b_2 \in M$ for $M$ such that
$M=b_1 \mathbb Z + b_2 \mathbb Z$. Then there is an integer valued matrix of determinant $\pm 1$ with

$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \varepsilon b_1 \\ \varepsilon b_2 \end{pmatrix}.$

From that you can deduce equations like $\varepsilon = a+b b_2/b_1$. But **I couldn't find** a monic polynomial with root $\varepsilon$ and integer coefficients. When I have that I would be done since this shows $\varepsilon \in \mathcal O_K$ and we get with the same argument $\varepsilon^{-1} \in \mathcal O_K$, so we are done.

**EDIT:** Now **I found** the monic polynomial (thanks to Barry Smith). It is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix because $\varepsilon$ is an eigenvalue of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  my original answer made an unnecessary assumption and was too complicated, but contained the essence of what was needed (as principal-ideal-domain pointed out).  Here is the simplified version:

Your matrix equation shows that $\varepsilon$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix.  The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is monic, with integer coefficients, hence $\varepsilon$ is an algebraic integer.  Then, as you pointed out, $\varepsilon^{-1}$ is an algebraic integer too, so they are both units.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming $\varepsilon$ is an algebraic integer. That's what I want to show. In my question I reasoned that that's actually everything we need to show. But thanks for your answer nevertheless because it led me to a solution of the problem: $\varepsilon$ is indeed an eigenvalue of the matrix. Hence it is a zero of the characteristic polynomial which is monic with integer coefficients. Hence $\varepsilon$ is an algebraic integer! QED.

Comment: Haha, yeah, that's simpler!

Comment: I kind of want to give you credit for your answer because it helped me to realize that $\varepsilon$ is an eigenvalue which was the clue to solve the problem. But accepting your answer seems wrong to me since it's not the answer of my problem ;). So what shall we do now?

Comment: Is the edit satisfactory?

Comment: It is, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In case that $M$ is a fractional ideal this answer is simple: $ M = \varepsilon M =(\varepsilon) M $, so the principal ideal generated by $\varepsilon$ has to be $\mathcal O_K$. Hence, $\varepsilon \in \mathcal O_K$.